# How to tell when an angularjs ui.router view with subviews has fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angularjs app that is using ui-router. I have a page with subviews. I want to know when the page is fully loaded similar to document.ready. I know that angularjs has the `$viewContentLoaded` event, but that fires for each subview. So when you add that it will fire for each of your subviews. Does anyone know of a way to listen for an event that would let me know the whole page has finished loading?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the `$stateChangeSuccess` event, and leverage the parameters however you wish (e.g. if you wanted to do something only for a specific `toState`)

> $stateChangeSuccess - fired once the state transition is complete.

An example may include...

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    // done -- do something
});
```

You can include this in places such as a controller or somewhere globally such as the `run` function and bind to `$rootScope`

See the [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) for more information

Comment: Well I don't think that would help in my case as I would have to hard code every "parent" state to see if that is the one that gave a success. I would like a solution that is more dynamic and can apply to any page.

Also does this event only fire off once the whole page has been processed?

Comment: This can apply to any page. Can you explain a littler more what you are concerned abut?

Comment: @FedilGrogan have you made any progress on this? Did this resolve your issue or send you in the right direction? Please let me know